# Where can I find more information about this equation

Tags: summation

Is this equation special somehow?

$$
\frac{\sum{xy}}{\sum{x}}
$$

Can this be simplified or written alternately?

Or is this its most basic form already?

Sorry for not using the right mathematical terms here... mainly wondering if I should try to simplify this further before implementing in SIMD software

EDIT: Summation over finite Number of items, not infinite summation

Comment: What's the index of the summation? If it's $x$, then the sum just equals $y$:
$$\frac{\sum_{x=1}^N xy}{\sum_{x=1}^N x} = y$$

Comment: Assuming that $x_i$ is a weight then it's the weighted average of $y_i$. For example, if $x_i=1$, it's the standard mean. Apart from that, I don't see much other information here.

Comment: It is an expression not an equation, and might be better written $\dfrac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_iy_i}{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i}$ or perhaps $\dfrac{\mathbf{x \cdot y}}{\mathbf{x \cdot 1}}$

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

It is the result of
doing a linear least squares fit
of $y=ax$ to a set of
$(x, y)$ data points.